# how do I find a curve fit model is good for the data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a 2D array and I am trying to fit a curve on the data. my objective function is a polynomial function:

```
def objective(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c
```

I used `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` to find the suitable curve for the data. But, I need to know how much this model is good. what is the difference between actual data and estimated curve?
how can I find this? dose `curve_fit` use mean square error to find the curve? how can I control this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), setting the input argument `full_output` to `True`, the function returns some additional information about the optimization; in particular, the function returns a dictionary (`infodict`) with an entry `fvec`, that contains the residuals (`y - y_star`) evaluated at the solution. Moreover, the default method used for the optimization is the least squares, if applicable (look at the `method` argument).

So, if you want to know the error of the fitted function, you can use those information:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def objective(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
data = objective(x, 1, 2, 3) + np.random.normal(0, 10, (len(x),))

potp, pcov, info, msg, ier = curve_fit(objective, x, data, full_output=True,  method='lm')
y_hat = objective(x, *potp.tolist())

# residuals are in the entry 'fvec' of the info dict.
# These are the residuals evaluated at the solution, i.e., f(x) - data
# Compute sum of squared residuals
err = np.dot(info['fvec'], info['fvec'])
```

This is the plot representing the original data and the interpolation in the previous code

[image]

Moreover, the documentation states that `curve_fit` uses [leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) as optimization method if bounds are not provided; in particular, it tries to minimize the sum of squares of an error function. If bounds are provided or the number of observations is less than the number of variables, `curve_fit` uses [least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares); `least_square` solves a bounded nonlinear least-squares problem.

Comment: the err variable shows the square error of the original and interpolated function, right? which method curve_fit uses to minimize the error between actual and interpolated data?

Comment: Yes, the `err` variable is the sum of squared errors. For the second question, please  look at the answer: I've updated it.

Comment: if I want to calculate min-max optimization instead of least square, is it possible with curve_fit?

Comment: You can take a look at the `minimize` function in the `optimize` module of  `scipy` library.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using [np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) to do polynomial fits.